# React innerHTML with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to render a text, and then after a few seconds, change the contents of the text in React.

So what I've tried is having a simple `h1` in my code, and then in `componentDidMount` (correct place?) do a simple:

```
const node = document.querySelectorAll('#header')[0];
setTimeout(() => {
  node.innerHTML = 'second text';
}, 3000);
```

and then in the `render` method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <h1 id="header">test</h1>
)};
```

I get an error:

> cannot set property innerHTML of undefined

I googled this a bit and found something about a `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but I really can't see how is it related to this simple example. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is very much not how to use React :)

Comment: @Dominic yep, had a brainfart. Correct answer is below, my whole approach was so not React.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I mean, if you're using React, you should drop raw DOM manipulation (except in a few cases), it's usually a bad idea.

Plus you can easily do this using react declarative pattern:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: 'my text'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ text: 'my updated text' });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render () {
    return <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>;
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, this is 100% correct. Maybe I just had a slow day, duh.

Answer (score 1):

By manipulating the raw DOM you are undermining React's ability to optimise renders. In the case above, you can easily set the value from your component's state, calling setState when the timeout ends

`setTimeout(() => this.setState({text: 'second value'}))
  ...
  render () {
    return <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>`
  }

If you really need to access the DOM element directly React provides an advanced ref attribute that will pass through the element when it's created, rather than using a query selector which will have to traverse the entire DOM. But, there isn't a need to do this in the case presented above.

`<h1 ref={(ref) => {this.h1Ref = ref}}>{this.state.text}</h1>`

Comment: Thanks! Great solutions as well.